# set position of div from code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

Using a JQuery pop up DIV and positioning it just below the header with

```
position: { my: "top+43", at: "bottom", of: $("header") },
```

I can do this with

```
function loadPopUp(popUpMessage) {
    $("#saveDialogSingleFeature").dialog({
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto",
        minHeight: "none",
        position: { my: "top+43", at: "bottom", of: $("header") },
        show: { effect: "slideDown" },
         hide: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        buttons:[]

    }).parent().appendTo("form:first");
```

and it all works fine....However I need to apply this same position to a div, from code behind...my attempts are :

```
//div is 'SavedInfo'
SavedInfo.InnerHtml = "$('#saveDialogSingleFeature').dialog({position: { my: 'top+43', at: 'bottom', of: $('header') }}).parent().appendTo('form:first');";

SavedInfo.Attributes["style"] = "position: { my: 'top+45', at: 'bottom', of: $('header') }";
```

no joy...any ideas?

Comment: I have not seen this kind of position proprety like my,at, off in my whole life. what kind of this code. or you have written it ownself.

Comment: it seems it's from jquery UI http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Comment: @nirmal it is jquery ui https://api.jqueryui.com/position/...@john why dont you put it in hidden field and get the value in jquery

Comment: ok thanks @Zaki and and john for info

Comment: @John can you provide full html ?